# Feature Count for Categorized Layers with the Atlas function of Print Layout in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-print-layouts, feature-count

In QGIS, is it possible to count the features of each class in a categorized layer where the features being counted are limited to those that are inside the current atlas feature?

[image: Feature count for all features in the layer]

I have tried turning on "Filter Legend by Map Content" combined with the filter expression `intersects($geometry,@atlas_geometry)`, but the result remains the total feature count, and, is not restricted to the feature count of the atlas feature.

I am aware that I can count features within an atlas feature using a label, but, then it is not part of the legend.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to make a virtual layer that that summarises the layer, and, then add an attribute table to the print atlas.  For example, if the following query is used to create a virtual layer:

```
SELECT atlas_polygon.name, points.class, SUM(points.number) AS number, COUNT(points.class) AS location, atlas_polygon.geometry
FROM points
INNER JOIN
atlas_polygon
ON
st_intersects(points.geometry, atlas_polygon.geometry)
GROUP BY atlas_polygon.name, points.class
```

Then it's results will be shown for each atlas feature bu checking the box "Show only features intersecting atlas feature" in the attribute table on the Print Layout.

[image: Attribute Table settings on the Print Layout]

It would be awesome to also show the layer symbols on the attribute table Print Layout but that is another problem.